# That was about as good as it got for the visitors

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> That was about as good as it got for the visitors.

What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means:

Somebody telling the other that what they did was virtually the best thing possibly they could do to the visitors. They couldn't do any better.